# so its my 1st time using console.log at Java and I cant really identify my error

Tags: java, console.log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjskc.png)

mostly my error comes at the ".log" and whe i remove the .log at the header the error will be at every ".log" at the case

```
import java.io.Console.log;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.out.println("1-     Cheeseburger        55.00");
        System.out.println("2-     Pepsi               25.00");
        System.out.println("3-     Chips               35.00");
        System.out.print("choose item (0- exit): ");
 
      String choice = "Cheeseburger";
       Console console =  System.console();
    switch (choice) {
      
   case "Cheeseburger":
    console.log("Cheeseburger are 55.00 a pound.");
    break;
  case "Pepsi ":
    console.log("Pepsi  are 25.00 ");
    break;
  case "Chips":
    console.log("Bananas are 35.00");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Sorry, we are out of " + choice + ".");
}

console.log("Is there anything else you'd like?");
  }
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have a `console.log`; that _is_ available in JavaScript, which, despite the name, is an unrelated language.

Comment: Stick to `System.out .println() `, it does what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this and my error is the very ".log" in every case

Comment: @Percival remove the import and use `System.out.println()` or  `console.printf` instead of the `console.log`. Or you can use any logging library like `slf4j`.

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Console.html). It does not have a `log()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Java has `console.log`. You could use `console.printf` I guess.

It seems like you may be confusing Java and JavaScript though, and it might be better if you just use `System.out.println`.